# Is it possible in Firebase to setCustomClaims with curl?

Tags: firebase, curl, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set setCustomClaims on a user
with curl. Is it possible?
So far I got this

```
curl 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:setCustomClaims?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"email":"[user@example.com]","password":"[PASSWORD]"}'
```